# What does `netstat -antupe` mean?

Tags: command-line, netstat

What does the command

```
netstat -antupe
```

actually mean?

I understand that `netstat` is used to view the status of the Network but what does the `-antupe` flag do?

Comment: why not `man netstat`  ??  a=all sockets, n=numeric output.....  just as per manual page..

Comment: @guiverc I believe the OP thought that `-antupe` was one tag, meaning the man page wouldn't have helped

Answer (score 3):

Although it may seem that the tag `-antupe` is a 'word,' the tag itself is a combination of the tags `-a -n -t -u -p -e`.  This can be confirmed by comparing the output of:

```
netstat -antupe
```

And the output of

```
netstat -a -n -t -u -p -e
```

The outputs are exactly the same! As for the function (taken from `man netstat`):

- `-a, --all`: Show both listening and non-listening sockets.  With the --interfaces option, show interfaces that are not up
- `-n, --numeric`: Show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host, port or user names
- `-t`: (Couldn't find documentation, might be incorrect) Only looks accross tcp protocols
- `-u`: (Couldn't find documentation, might be incorrect) Only looks accross udp protocols
- `-p, --programs`: Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs
- `-e, --extend`: Display additional information.  Use this option twice for maximum detail